# RectifyNodelet was not subscribing to image_mono

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to customize  Imageproc node to add a time stamp on each input frame. The output from mono was perfectly fine. The Image from mono has time stamp on it.

But the RectifyNodelet was not able to subscribe to It.
I have converted raw_msg to a cv::Mat and the used putText for stamping arrival time on it. Then converted the same to sensors:msg using CvImage().toImageMsg

Could anybody please let me know what might be the reason.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254919/rectifynodelet-was-not-subscribing-to-image_mono/) by [mkreddy477](https://answers.ros.org/users/29390/mkreddy477/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was a sync problem. I was able to solve the problem by simply passing the header of raw_msg to the CvImage(). Previously I was not passing the default header.

---

Originally posted by [mkreddy477](https://answers.ros.org/users/29390/mkreddy477/) with karma: 58 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0